# How do I solve this? (Saving money with increasing income)

Tags: summation, economics

I have to solve this for my homework.

The question goes like: If you get an income of 1 million USD per year. And each consecutive year your income increases by 10% than the previous year. How many years will it take for you to save up a total of 1 billion USD if you save 20% of your yearly income each year in a piggy bank.

And I’m suppose to solve it with a single formula, where i plug in 1 million, 10%, 1 billion, 20%, and get the amount of years it will take after solving it.

Edit. Basically the best I’ve been able to solve it is by doing it on excel. I basically make one column (A) starting with 1 million then each row increasing by 10%. Then the column (B) next to that as 20% of the Box in the same row as it in column A plus the number above it. And the just seeing how many rows it takes until it reaches a number just above 1 billion.

I’m not sure how to condense it all into 1 formula where it the result is a integer of how many years it’ll take until it reaches the desired number.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: In particular, let us know the formula you're attempting to use and how you're trying to use it.

Comment: I’m trying to solve it in excel and essentially have it but I really just have multiple formulas and spreadsheet boxes. I’m stuck in how to make this all one single formula. Technically I already do know the answer, but it has to be solved as simply as possible.

Comment: Let $x$ be the first year's income.  What is your total savings at the end of year 1? At the end of year 2? etc. Write down the sequence displaying this desired information. Use the pattern that emerges to derive the desired formula.    If you're new to such problems, perhaps start with a slightly simpler problem: each year, save your entire income instead of just $20\%$ of it.